# Firefox - show line number on "function not defined"?

Tags: javascript, onerror

I need to track JS errors in browser, but when I run the function in FF I get 'function not defined' error. It does not give me a line number. It works in Chrome and maybe in IE too.

```
    window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
  var loggerUrl = "https://www.xing.com/js/logger";
  var parameters = "?description=" + escape(errorMessage)
      + "&amp;url=" + escape(url)
      + "&amp;line=" + escape(line)
      + "&amp;parent_url=" + escape(document.location.href)
      + "&amp;user_agent=" + escape(navigator.userAgent);

  /** Send error to server */
  //new Image().src = loggerUrl + parameters;
  alert(loggerUrl + parameters);
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" onClick="test()" value="click">
```

Comment: `escape` is not for URLs; use `encodeURIComponent` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I actually dont know what escape and encode are doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good firefox addon "Firebug" which is exactely what you're looking for.  Search Firebug in the Mozilla addon website.

Comment: I used that, but i will like to store all errors in a database from all users. This way I get a JS Error log.

Firebug do not return a linenumbers eather

Comment: Wait-why do you want to send errors to a database?  Shouldn't the code be tested before put into production?

Comment: Of course it is tested before, but with many developers, different old browsers errors will always be there.